# Handling overlays on Google Streetview custom panoramas

Tags: google-maps-api-3, google-street-view

i'm trying to use overlays on a custom google StreetView Panorama. 
I was able to simply put one on my pano, but the position is totally random (i made some attempts until the effect was alright), and the change of rendering mode (in chrome which renders as a sphere) changes the effect. 
The problem is clear: the custom panorama has no information about its dimensions (it has only a LatLng), so the relative positions are wrong.
Am i missing something?
The only thing i need is to put some clickable labels on the walls of a room, which modify themselves along with the rotating panorama. I searched a lot, but my efforts were inconclusive.
Mapsicle seemed to do what i needed, but if i understood correcly it's a dead project.

Comment: Please include some code, a link, or a jsFiddle URL. What is the exact problem you are having? Are you generating errors? We need more information to help you.

Comment: there is no error, it's a conceptual problem.